# Homebrew update failure on mac

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

Upon doing a `brew update`, I get the following errors:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
Error: Fetching /usr/local failed!
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask failed!
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Does it work if you run `brew install git` then try again?

Comment: this seems to have solved the problem, thanks bfontaine!

Comment: You’re welcome; I added this as an answer so that the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue with your `git` install; you can fix it by updating to the latest version with the following command:

```
brew install git
```

Comment: This helped me get things working.  Note that I had to do `brew update` more than once following this.

Comment: This had no effect on my machine. Mine could be due to the Monterey upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well, and for me it was because the repo in question was cloned via ssh, and my private key is password protected.  To fix this I used `ssh-agent`.

```
eval `ssh-agent`

ssh-add
```

Once I added my key and input my password, `brew update` succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me, but isn't mine.

I found it in the [brew's github discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/52#issuecomment-208557489).

> There is some issue with your SSH setup.
>
> And you seem to be rewriting https://github.com/ remotes to
> git@github.com: as can be seen from the last output.
>
> Please check your `~/.gitconfig` for a line similar to `insteadOf = https://github.com/` that you must have added at some point in time
> (or some tool did for you) to your configuration.
>
> Please comment that out by prefixing the line with # and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because brew is pointed to a nonstandard github origin. Use the following command to point brew to the right github URL.

> git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

Run brew update after this.

Comment: Mine still fails following this attempt as well.